# Postgresql existing users wont authenticate

Tags: postgresql, fedora, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to install postgresql 9.1 on fedora 17.

It was wasy to yum install it, but I'm having a difficult time connecting to it.

I have made changes to the pg_hba.conf, I know I have the users created (\l shows my users) but for some reason when I try to connect using pgAdmin it won't authenticate.

Here is my pg_hba.conf:

```
#Allow any IP to connect, with a password:
host    all         all         0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      trust
host    all         all         ::1/128                       trust
local   all         all                                       trust
```

Anyone else experienced anyhting like this? Some other changes that need to be made?

Comment: Just to verify: 1.) You did restart your pgsql server, 2.) you are connecting from pgadmin the same way as with psql? (TCP/IP vs. Sockets) Does psql -h 127.0.0.1 work?

Comment: What's the exact error message when it fails to authenticate? Also note that the `\l` command shows databases, not users.

Comment: Is postmaster actually running?

Comment: Your `pg_hba` allows anyone to connect __without__ a password. Try to connect with `psql` and show the command line and the error message.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! I did restart the server, I try to runt the psql -h 127.0.0.1 (with -U and -W) it gives me this: psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "test". I did a \du and it shows that my user has the following roles: Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication. @AlexHowansky, it should be up and running, I did a netstat -an | grep PG and something is listening (not sure this is the best way to check).

Comment: So here's what's happened, I uninstalled postgresql (yum erase) downloaded the .run from postgresql's page and it just worked for me. Still this doesn't really answer what's wrong but it's a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the above two commands do not work try the following:

```
postgresql-setup initdb
```

Comment: Thanks for the followup! In the end I just downloaded a tar and did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

After installing postgresql server through yum like this (or something similar):

```
yum install postgresql91-server postgresql91-contrib
```

you should execute the following:

```
service postgresql-9.1 initdb
chkconfig postgresql-9.1 on
```

[This page](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/) has more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think 0.0.0.0 should be 0.0.0.0/0

And try restarting PostgreSQL after that.  I find sometimes reloading doesn't work.